# I'm trying to build HellowWorld with Gradle; can't make it compile

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to build HelloWorld project with Gradle. Seems that I'm following instructions:

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin 'java'
```

This is my java file:

```
package my;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(“hello, world”);

    }

}
```

my java file is in

grtest/src/main/my/

folder

my build.gradle is in grtest/

When I do

gradle build

It creates grtest/build/grtest.jar

but that jar just contains manifest, but does not contain class file

I'm doing it on windows command line, I have java, javac in the path.

How to make it compile?

Comment: Did you set the JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Yes, JAVA_HOME is set; java -version and javac -version are responding. No complaints from gradle is coming upon execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that by default the java plugin expects your java sources to be located under `src/main/java/...`, resources to be located under `src/main/resources`, etc. (all paths are under to your project directory, `grtest` in this case ). Since your source code is located under `src/main/my` then Gradle could not find any file to compile under `src/main/java/...`, thus you got an empty jar.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, Ammon. Sorry, missed that part. It still requires 'java' under 'main'.